# Sorting dataframe by two columns in Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm getting the following error from the code below:

```
***File "<ipython-input-61-517e344a129d>", line 1
    df.sort_values(by "Script Count", "Drug Name"), axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort',
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax*** (the carrot is pointing to the second " following "Script Count")
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('/Users/rmartin/Desktop/DE_Highmark.csv')

df.sort_values(by "Script Count", "Drug Name"), axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
```

I know this must be super simple, but I've driven myself crazy trying to figure it out. I'm trying to sort the dataframe based on the `"Script Count"` and `"Drug Name"` columns from a dataframe. The CSV was successfully imported as a dataframe, but the sort function is giving me trouble.

Comment: Try df.sort_values(by = [ "Script Count", "Drug Name"], axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')

Answer (score 2):

Refering to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values), the right syntax is:

```
 DataFrame.sort_values(by, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last')
```

so in your case, it should be:

```
df.sort_values(by=[ "Script Count", "Drug Name"], ascending=[True,True])
```

Comment: Let's get the current version docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values